# Как с помощью PHP или JS уложить разноразмерные изображения в мозаику?

Tags: php, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Как с помощью PHP или JS красиво укладывать разноразмерные изображения в единую мозаику (как во "ВКонтакте" на стенах)?

В последнем, как я понял, на стороне клиента за это отвечает файл http://st3.vk.me/js/al/thumbs_edit.js?17 , но я так и не смог его разобрать.

jQuery Masonry не предлагать. Вообще, предпочтительнее решение на PHP.

Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На [javascript](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/08/30/automatic-image-montage/), на [PHP](http://habrahabr.ru/post/135421/) (правда ссылки на исходники уже не рабочие).

Comment: JS нежелателен, а по PHP-варианту - там как-то много комментариев про тормознутость кода, дескать, ожидание длится минутами.

Comment: вы когда-то слышали про кэширование миниатюр? Вот если у вас есть 100 картинок, сколько раз вы должны просчитать им ширину и высоту и согранить миниатюры чтобы выложить мозаикой? Не уж то каждый раз будете пересчитывать? Или сделаете один раз, а потом выведете все это сколько угодно раз когда попросят?

Comment: У меня ширина и высота изображения хранится в базе данных. Или я что-то не так понял?

Comment: Я говорю про тормознутость кода о том, что просчет мозаики можно свести к одному разу и скорость выдачи такой мозаики будет очень быстрой. И все те кто говорит, что это медленно работает просто забывают о важных вещах - таких как кэширование.

Comment: То есть, можно хранить результаты вычислений в БД в JSON`e, и потом на его основе выводить HTML, так?

Comment: вариантов масса, во первых при вычислении мозаики все картинки (миниатюры с вычисенными размерами - сохранит отдельно), результаты этих вычислений тоже в json или еще куда. И при запросе к странице проверять есть ли в кэше страница с такими параметрами при запросе (скажем кешируете по фильтру из GET запроса) и если нету то создаем и сохраняем если есть просто выдаем то что есть.

Comment: Понятно.
Кстати, решение с PHP, указанное в ответе, помогло - всё укладывается равномерно. Пришлось, правда, адаптировать код под мой способ хранения данных о фотографиях. Теперь осталось только сделать кэширование результатов вычислений, и всё.